# Oracle Procedure - JOIN with Subquery

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, alias, outer-join

I need some help finishing this procedure. The problem is how to alias the different SELECTs so that I can match them on the RIGHT OUTER JOIN. The traditional AS doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
PROCEDURE "GetProcessedEvents"
(
"In_OccurredFrom" TIMESTAMP,
"In_OccurredTo" TIMESTAMP,
"In_Interval" DECIMAL,
"Out_Cursor" OUT "Ref_Cursor"
)
IS
BEGIN    
OPEN "Out_Cursor" FOR      
  SELECT
    COUNT("Id") AS "ProcessedEvents",
    TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DATEDIFF('MI', '1900-01-01', "ProcessedDate")/"In_Interval")*"In_Interval", 'MINUTE') AS "EventDts"
  FROM "Dat_ScheduledEvent"
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT "Dts" FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredTo", "In_OccurredFrom", "In_Interval")))
  ON "EventDts" = "Dts"
  WHERE
    "ProcessedDate" BETWEEN "In_OccurredFrom" AND "In_OccurredTo"
  GROUP BY
    TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DATEDIFF('MI', '1900-01-01', "ProcessedDate")/"In_Interval")*"In_Interval", 'MINUTE');
END "GetProcessedEvents";
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? What doesn't work? Are you getting the wrong data or does it just not work? Maybe a description of what it is supposed to do might help too. All this malarkey with "In_interval" is a bit hard to fathom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS` is optional when aliasing columns, but not allowed at all by Oracle when aliasing tables, including subqueries. So give the subquery a name, just don't include the `AS` keyword:

```
  FROM "Dat_ScheduledEvent" alias1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT "Dts"
    FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredTo", "In_OccurredFrom",
      "In_Interval"))
  ) alias2
```

But you have some other problems. Firstly, creating objects with identifiers that have to be enclosed in double quotes is painful to work with; is having mixed-case identifier really worth it? Secondly, it looks like `EventDts` is only a derived field, and a column alias can't be used anywhere else in the query other than an `order by` clause, so you probably need to make that a subquery too - which means you can use it in the `group by` too. Thirdly, `DATEDIFF` is not a built-in Oracle function - unless you've created that yourself you'll need to use something else.

```
  SELECT
    COUNT(alias1."Id") AS "ProcessedEvents",
    alias1."EventDts"        
  FROM (
    SELECT "Id",
      TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
        + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DATEDIFF('MI', '1900-01-01', "ProcessedDate")
          /"In_Interval")*"In_Interval", 'MINUTE') AS "EventDts"
    FROM "Dat_ScheduledEvent"
    WHERE "ProcessedDate" BETWEEN "In_OccurredFrom" AND "In_OccurredTo"
  ) alias1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT "Dts"
    FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredTo", "In_OccurredFrom",
      "In_Interval"))
  ) alias2
  ON alias1."EventDts" = alias2."Dts"
  GROUP BY alias2."EventDts";
```

`DATEDIFF` still needs to be replaced, but I'm not quite sure what you're doing. If the `F_GetDateIntervalTable` is generating suitable intervals, I'm not sure why you need to do that at all; don't you want to find `ProcessedDate` values within the intervals, i.e. `>=`Dt`and <`Dt`+ InInterval`? Depending on what `InInterval` actually represents, of course.

---

Assuming `F_GetDateIntervalTable` gives you the start of each interval within the period of interest, you can do something like this instead:

```
PROCEDURE "GetProcessedEvents"
(
"In_OccurredFrom" TIMESTAMP,
"In_OccurredTo" TIMESTAMP,
"In_Interval" DECIMAL,
"Out_Cursor" OUT "Ref_Cursor"
)
IS
BEGIN    
OPEN "Out_Cursor" FOR
  SELECT
    COUNT(Event."Id") AS "ProcessedEvents",
    DateInt."Dts"
  FROM (
    SELECT "Dts", COALESCE(LEAD("Dts")
      OVER (ORDER BY "Dts"), "In_OccurredTo") as "NextDts"
    FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredTo", "In_OccurredFrom",
      "In_Interval"))
  ) DateInt
  LEFT JOIN "Dat_ScheduledEvent" Event
  ON Event."ProcessedDate" >= DateInt."Dts"
  AND Event."ProcessedDate" < DateInt."NextDts"
  GROUP BY DateInt."Dts"
  ORDER BY DateInt."Dts";
END "GetProcessedEvents";
/
```

The `LEAD()` lets you peek at the next result, so that subquery is converting a list of timestamps into a list of from- and to-timestamps (with the last one ending at `In_OccurredTo`), which allows you to look for matching records in your data table that fall within those ranges - no manipulation of the `ProcessedDate` is needed.

With some fake data:

```
create table "Dat_ScheduledEvent" ("Id" number, "ProcessedDate" timestamp);

insert into "Dat_ScheduledEvent" ("Id", "ProcessedDate")
  values (1, to_timestamp('2013-02-06 09:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
insert into "Dat_ScheduledEvent" ("Id", "ProcessedDate")
  values (1, to_timestamp('2013-02-06 09:50', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
insert into "Dat_ScheduledEvent" ("Id", "ProcessedDate")
  values (1, to_timestamp('2013-02-06 10:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

... and calling the procedure from SQL*Plus:

```
var r refcursor;
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI';
exec "GetProcessedEvents"(to_date('2013-02-06 08:00'), to_date('2013-02-06 12:00'), 1/24, :r);
print :r
```

... I get:

```
ProcessedEvents        Dts                       
---------------------- ------------------------- 
0                      06-FEB-13 08.00.00.000000000 
2                      06-FEB-13 09.00.00.000000000 
1                      06-FEB-13 10.00.00.000000000 
0                      06-FEB-13 11.00.00.000000000
```

Comment: The F_GetDateIntervalTable gets all the TimeStamps, some which might be missing from the set of statistics I'm retrieving.
So instead of getting 
    
    2013-01-01 00:00    100
    2013-01-01 02:00    130
    
    I get 
    
    2013-01-01 00:00    100
    2013-01-01 01:00    0
    2013-01-01 02:00    130
    
And yes I have added DATEDIFF as a local function. (I come from MSSQL)

Comment: Thank you! So extremely much. This has been giving me such a headache with countless of wasted hours trying to fiddle with it myself.

The only changes I made to it was removing a lot of the Events that arn't needed and switched places on the From and To in the COALESCE part.

Comment: `SELECT
 COUNT(Event."Id") AS "ProcessedEvents",
 DateInt."Dts"
FROM (
 SELECT "Dts", COALESCE(LEAD("Dts")
   OVER (ORDER BY "Dts"), "In_OccurredTo") as "NextDts"
 FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredFrom", "In_OccurredTo", "In_Interval"))
) DateInt
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM "Dat_ScheduledEvent" WHERE "ProcessedDate" >= "In_OccurredFrom" AND "ProcessedDate" < "In_OccurredTo") Event
ON Event."ProcessedDate" >= DateInt."Dts"
AND Event."ProcessedDate" < DateInt."NextDts"      
GROUP BY DateInt."Dts"
ORDER BY DateInt."Dts";`

Comment: @user902264 - glad it helped. I took the parameter order for the function call form your question, but thought it was odd. If there's an index on `ProcessedDate` then the subselect you added won't make much difference; if there isn't then it will be more noticeable.

Comment: I guess I messed up a lot then ;). Yeah the difference in time is like 30 sec vs 0,5 sec. Dat_ScheduledEvents is a table with 3 million+ rows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got some ideas.
**Might be usefull using** `WITH` clause, which allows you to break complex SELECT statements into subqueries which creatly improve structure of your code, and of course you can refer to them (subqueries) by alias.

Here is a small example of usage for you:

```
WITH subquery AS (SELECT sysdate FROM dual)
-- Here goes main query where subquery must be used
SELECT *
FROM subquery


OPEN "Out_Cursor" FOR     
WITH Q AS (SELECT "Dts" FROM TABLE("F_GetDateIntervalTable"("In_OccurredTo", "In_OccurredFrom", "In_Interval")))

SELECT
    COUNT("Id") AS "ProcessedEvents",
    TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DATEDIFF('MI', '1900-01-01', "ProcessedDate")/"In_Interval")*"In_Interval", 'MINUTE') AS "EventDts"
  FROM "Dat_ScheduledEvent"
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Q
  ON "EventDts" = "Dts"
  WHERE
    "ProcessedDate" BETWEEN "In_OccurredFrom" AND "In_OccurredTo"
  GROUP BY
    TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DATEDIFF('MI', '1900-01-01', "ProcessedDate")/"In_Interval")*"In_Interval", 'MINUTE');
END "GetProcessedEvents";
```

Comment: I ve tried using WITH, but where do I place it within the PROCEDURE without it whining?

I've tried putting it 

    `PROCEDURE
    AS
    WITH
    BEGIN`
    
    `BEGIN
    WITH
    OPEN`
    
    `OPEN FOR
    WITH
    SELECT`

none of them work sadly :(.

Comment: I haven`t tried it, but I might guess: after FOR or before OPEN

Comment: Error(14,7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITH" when expecting one of the following:     . ( % ; for

Comment: Ok, I made some adjustments to my answer related to the WITH clause

Comment: Still getting the error:
"PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WITH" when expecting one of the following: . ( % ; for", but thanks for answering anyways :).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double quotes around variable names, unless they are required by the syntax.  That could be confusing the parser.

Comment: EventDts is still an invalid identifier.